# Moving from sendfile() to sendFile() in Express

Tags: javascript, express

My code is as follows :

```
router.get('/image',(req,res,next)=>{
  const fileName = "path_to.jpg"
  res.sendfile(fileName,(err)=>{
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName);
    }
  });
})
```

When used as-is with Express 4 this router works via successfully sending the desired image to the client. However the server writes out a warning message about "res.sendfile" being deprecated and that I should switch to "res.sendFile" (( Just capitalize the "f" in "file" )).

```
express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead
```

When I do exactly that my functioning code no longer results in a 200 status but a 500. No other aspect is changed beyond that "f" becoming a capital letter.

Am I misunderstanding what the express warning is asking me to do?

I've referenced ( http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile ) and have not seen anything glaringly incorrect about my snippet of code... If there is other information I should provide please let me know.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile,  path must be an absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

By including the module "path" in the router I am then able to create an absolute path for sendFile() to use, as suggested by the comment made by @karthick on the original post.

So when calling sendFile() use a relative path to the file as the fileName and an absolute path created by "path" for the option "root".

Example below assumes that the image file is in the same folder as the router script.

```
router.get('/image',(req,res,next)=>{
const fileName = "1.jpg"
res.sendFile(fileName,{ root: path.join(__dirname, './') },(err)=>{
    if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    next(err)
    } else {
    console.log('Sent:', fileName);
    }
});
})
```